# How do you redirect traffic for all IP addresses on an AdHoc network?

Tags: linux, networking, redirection

Sometimes when I sign into a businesses WiFi network the server/router redirects all traffic to their sign in page where I have to click accept (or pay) before getting access to any other pages. How is this done? Is it done by the router or something else?

I have a RaspberryPi set up as a webserver and it broadcasts an adhoc network. Currently you have to type into the IP address of the server in order to view the web app when your connected to the ad hoc network. Is there a way I can make it intercept requests to any address and redirect them to my app?

Comment: In most cases this is done by the same hardware that is the acess point.  Since the RaspberryPi is not the access point additional hardware would have to be used.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes but in the case of an Ad Hoc network the RPi essentially is an access point.

Comment: Your first step would be to setup a captive portal on the device which might be difficult considering most ARM based devices in the sector would be contained with commercial products using non-open source software.

Answer (score 1):

What you have seen at work in businesses' wifi networks is technically called a [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal); in Wikipedia's words,

> The captive portal technique forces an HTTP client on a network to see a special web page (usually for authentication purposes) before using the Internet normally. A captive portal turns a Web browser into an authentication device.

In my experience, they are sometimes mis-configured, so that using a non-standard port (I use something in the *50,000* range) to connect to your home VPN allows you to by-pass authentication and use the network without any obstacle. Same thing for ssh connections through a non-standard port.

This configuration can be implemented on a Raspberry Pi, just Google the words *Raspberry Pi captive portal *, and you will find plenty of instructions on this. Not knowing whether you are running Raspian, Arch Linux, or OpenSuse (which I do not really know) I cannot be more specific, but there is much info around. You may start [here](http://www.raspihub.com/go/7ac37d33d3d4ab0f0050e0cb656b3153b5f3de389fa48b570db2977e353bf6fe), for clarity, if for nothing else.